# how to make sequence call with node-bitly api

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which i need to process url to short url within a text and publish the updated text.

work environment is node js.

Below code converts the url to short but as it is asyc i couldnt use it before processing further.

```
var url='myurl';
console.log("before bitly");
Bitly.shorten({longUrl: url}, function(err, results) {
        // Do something with your new, shorter url...
           var obj = JSON.parse(results);
           shorturl= obj.data.url;
           console.log(shorturl);
        });
console.log("after bitly");
```

Output:
before bitly |after bitly | "shorturl*

Expeced output:
before bitly | "shorturl* |after bitly

Comment: Put the line where you're decalring newval into the callback. It fails because shorturl is not define where you are.

Comment: Ok..got u..what i intended was to get a sequential call. i have edited my question to make it more clear...any inputs?

Comment: the ouput you expect is not possible, because your shorthen function is Async. So, once it has been called the js will execute the following code. So your console logs appear before the response of the server. That's a simple Async Javascript Basics. You can chain promise to solve it.

Comment: @Disfigure can you help me to implement chain promise on this as I am new to node js

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are not the best way to handle asynchronous processing, better to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

The async syntax makes it look like synchronous code but you'll need a recent version of node (V8) for that. Examples on mdn don't make much sense since they would call an async function and then handle the result as a promise, if that's how you use it you may as well stick with promises.

Promises look complicated but once you understand how JavaScript [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) works it gets easier.

According to the [bitly documentation](https://github.com/tanepiper/node-bitly) you code could look like this for promises:

```
const url='myurl';

Bitly.shorten(url)
.then(
  results =>{
    // Do something with your new, shorter url...
    const obj = JSON.parse(results);
    //having a global variable is not a good idea
    // shorturl= obj.data.url;
    console.log("got data:",obj.data.url);
    return obj.data.url;
  }
)
.then(
  shorturl => {
    //do something with short url
  }
)
.then(
  undefined
  ,reject =>//handle any errors
    console.error("Failed:",reject)
);
```

Comment: trying to execute above code result in below erorr - Bitly.shorten(...).then is not a function.

Comment: @ShiyasCholamukhath Maybe you have an old version of bitly installed, according to the documentation (https://github.com/tanepiper/node-bitly) it should work.

Comment: I am on Node 9.0.0 and "bitly": "^5.0.12". Still getting same error

Comment: @ShiyasCholamukhath you could try to copy and paste the example ( https://github.com/tanepiper/node-bitly ) and see if that runs. If it doesn't then try to debug the example: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/debugging-node-js-with-google-chrome-4965b5f910f4